# Add 30 minutes to a time read from a text file and compare against current time

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time, strftime

I'm trying to make a little script to use the time from a text file and then add 30 minutes to that number, then compare against "currenttime" to see if 30+ minutes have passed...

```
import os
from time import time, sleep, strftime

with open('timecheck.txt') as timecheck:
    last_timecheck = timecheck.read().strip()
    print last_timecheck 

currenttime = strftime('%H:%M:%S')
if last_timecheck + 30 >= currenttime:
    if os.path.exists("../test.csv"):
        with open("timecheck.txt", 'wb') as timecheck:
            timecheck.write("1")
    else:
        currenttime = strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        with open("timecheck.txt", 'wb') as timecheck:
            timecheck.write(currenttime)
```

Any help would be appreciated, I can't figure out how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating a string for the current time, *parse the string read from the file*, using [`datetime.datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) for example:

```
import datetime

last_timecheck = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_timecheck, '%H:%M:%S')
last_timecheck = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), last_timecheck.time())

if last_timecheck + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30) <= datetime.datetime.now():
```

This checks if *more than 30 minutes* have passed.

You *probably* should include the *date* in the information you write to the file. If you don't, then `23:30:45` will never be '30 minutes ago' on the *current day*.

If you don't need the timestamp to be human-readable, just write seconds since the UNIX epoch:

```
timecheck.write(str(time.time()))
```

That's a floating point value, and you can read it again with:

```
last_timecheck = float(timecheck.read())
```

Since it is a numeric representation, you can then test if 30 minutes have passed with:

```
if last_timecheck + 30 <= time.time():
```

Comment: And perhaps you could have the best of both worlds: human readable and UNIX seconds.

Comment: I struggle to work out how to use the datetime version but the unix way was easy and I'm using that way because I couldn't care less about it being readable.